# Null character persistence in Java input buffer?

Tags: java, input

I'm running a loop to accept input. Strangely, my program seems to think I have a null character when my buffer is supposed to be empty. I've written up a little class to demonstrate.

NullCharTest:

```
package Scratch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class NullCharTest {

    public void testNullChar() throws IOException{

        for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

            String s = readString();
            while (s != null) {
                s = readString();
            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private String readString() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return in.readLine();
    }

}
```

Main:

```
package Scratch;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        NullCharTest nct = new NullCharTest();
        nct.testNullChar();
    }

}
```

The output is something like:

q
w
e
null
null
[[**Edit**: the output is just null, null, as pointed out by Andreas.]]

I input Ctrl+D after entering 'e'.

Why doesn't the for loop take in input the second time it runs? s isn't null the second time around- it's a fresh String reference that's just been asked to reference a readString() output... so presumably my program should wait around for user input on the second run of the for loop...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is meaningless:

```
String s = readString();
while (s != null) {
    s = readString();
}
```

By the time the `while` loop ends, `s` *will* be null, because that is the only way for the loop to complete normally.

You then print the value of `s`, i.e. you print the value `null`.

This is surrounded by a `for` loop that iterates 2 times, which means that it will *always* end up printing `null` twice.

The `q w e` is not output, but the input you typed. The output is `null` and `null`. Always, regardless of what you type before pressing `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: Why doesn't the for loop take in input the second time it runs? s isn't null the second time around- it's just been asked to do a readString(), so presumably it should wait around for user input... (Added to question as an edit)

Comment: @Learning... Because when you press `Ctrl+D`, you are ending all input. You are basically closing `System.in`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify it like below :

```
String s = readString();
while (s != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
    s = readString();
}
```